# background: none в  ie8

Tags: html5, css

Что делать с фоном...ставлю background: none но вместо этого белый фон появляется. Пробовал фильтры с opacity но там вообще все пропадает. Что надо сделать?
Мне надо убрать фон у дива так, чтобы было видно фон другого дива под ним...

Comment: Покажите сайт или кусок кода с проблемным блоком и родительским блоком + стили для них. Проблем с background: none возникать не должно, возможно проблема в другом.

Comment: Сейчас скину ссылку

Comment: http://kamvek.16mb.com/ там на слайдере белый фон вылазит...хрен знает че с ним сделать((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Тебя на `<div class=slide>` зачем-то повешен  `background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)`, что естественно делает белый фон. В стилях у тебя этого вроде нет, видимо в JS.

Comment: я ему прописал в стилях background: none !important; вроде все нормально стало

Answer (score 1):

если стандартными средствами не получается попробуйте присвоить вашему диву цвет дива родителя. На jquery так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div2").css("background-color",$("#div1").css("background-color"));
}
```

div2 - соответственно тот див с которым у вас проблемы

Comment: ну можно и через .parent 
http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Answer (score 1):

Да, в IE есть проблема с наследуемыми значениями. Попробуйте задать свойство таким образом:

```
.your_block {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```